# SQL query, string datetime condition to Entity Framework Core and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to perform a query with a condition doing a date and string comparison. Examples of queries that are currently running are as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyData 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 6) LIKE '%25 Jun 23%'
```

I tried to do the conversion on linq but it didn't work.

Here's the linq I've tried and it throws an error:

```
await _context.MyData
        .Where(x => x.UpdateDate != null &&  
            Convert.ToDateTime(x.UpdateDate).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
            .Contains(searchValue))
        .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

I did the query using Entity Framework Core. How to do the query above using Linq?

Comment: Dates are binary types, not strings. Use the correct type in the database and entity model. Even if this query could be converted to SQL, it would return the wrong results *and* have terrible performance

Comment: Whatever query you want to perform, there are ways to do it with good performance. For example, to search for a date, as long as the field is a `date`, you can just compare it with the date you want, `x=>x.UpdateDate=new DateTime(2023,6,25)`. To find items in April 2023  `x=>x.UpdateDate >= new DateTime(2023,4,1) && x.UpdateDate<new DateTime(2023,5,1)`.

Comment: `WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateField,6) LIKE '%25 Jun 23%'` is never used for a *lot* of reasons. The inexcusable Y2K bug, the lack of indexing that results in a full table scan. The localized conversion that means you may *not* get `Jun` at all, resulting in lost results.

Comment: I use this query for search queries according to what is input by the user and I use the "dd MMM yy" format on the display. So that the results of the search query will display according to the data displayed on the screen

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. Any formats are applied by the rendering code. They don't exist in the database. If `UpdateDate` is a string, you have a major bug. And `23` as the year - what is that? 1923? 2023? You have no way of knowing, only assuming. And that assumption can easily be wrong as many major banks found out in January 2020. [Y2K? How about Y2.02K as Lloyds suffers its second TITSUP* of the year](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/)

Comment: If you use a DatePicker in the UI you get back a DateTime object, not a string. In HTML, the value of an `input type='date'` is always in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. There's no reason to use the display text in fields and queries

Comment: Thank you for your attention and information, @PanagiotisKanavos, I have to search and change my search concept.

Comment: Basically you convert the user input to `DateTime` not the other way round. Then you would do something like `.Where(x => x.UpdateDate >= userUpdateDate && x.UpdateDate < userUpdateDate.AddDays(1))` note that you don't need to check for null because SQL deals with nulls anyway.

Comment: The problem is this search is a global search on a table. So it is possible that what is input by the user is not the date.